# Using cat and grep commands in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep, cat

I'm having trouble with trying to achieve this bash command:

Concatenate all the text files in the current directory that have at least one occurrence of the word `BOB` (in any case) within the text of the file.

Is it correct for me to do this use the `cat` command then use `grep` to find the occurences of the word `BOB`?

```
cat grep -i [BOB] *.txt > catFile.txt
```

Comment: The regular expression `[BOB]` matches a singe character which can be either `B` or `O` (duplicates inside the square brackets are simply ignored). Without quoting, if you have any file names matching the pattern, the shell will replace `[BOB]` with a list of the matching file names, according to somewhat different rules (glob pattern, not regular expression).

Comment: `cat grep` does not run two commands; it runs `cat` with the argument `grep` (which will be an error unless there is a file in the current directory with the name `grep` to concatenate with the other arguments to `cat`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To handle filenames with whitespace characters correctly:

```
grep --null -l -i "BOB" *.txt | xargs -0 cat > catFile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue was the need to pass `grep`'s file names to `cat` as an inline function:

```
cat $(grep --null -l -i "BOB" *.txt ) > catFile.txt
```

- `$(.....)` handles the inline execution
- `-l`  returns only filenames of the things that matched

Comment: This is good unless the file names contain whitespace or other shell-active characters.  A more reliable approach would use `grep --null` combined with `xargs --null`.

Comment: `$(some bash command)` will execute this code at the time it is reached in the processing of the line.  So, here it will take the output of all that occurs within the parens, and pass it to `cat`, after which whose output will direct with `>`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `find` with `-exec`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -exec grep -qi 'bob' {} \; \
    -exec cat {} + > catFile.txt
```

- `-maxdepth 1` makes sure you don't search any deeper than the current directory
- `-name '*.txt'` says to look at all files ending with `.txt` – for the case that there is also a *directory* ending in `.txt`, you could add `-type f` to only look at files
- `-exec grep -qi 'bob' {} \;` runs grep for each `.txt` file found. If `bob` is in the file, the exit status is zero and the next directive is executed. `-q` makes sure the grep is silent.
- `-exec cat {} +` runs `cat` on all the files that contain `bob`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the square brackets...

```
grep -il "BOB" *
```

Comment: That's not the only problem.  You might want to expand on the issue of how to combine `cat` with `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following command that you must run from the directory containing your `BOB` files.

```
grep -il BOB *.in | xargs cat > BOB_concat.out
```

- `-i` is an option used to set `grep` in `case insensitive mode`
- `-l` will be used to output only the filename containing the pattern provided as argument to grep
- `*.in` is used to find all the input files in the dir (should be adapted to your folder content)
- then you pipe the result of the command to `xargs` in order to build the arguments that cat will use to produce your file concatenation.

**HYPOTHESIS:**

- Your folder does only contain files without strange characters in their name (e.g. space)